# Difference between these two lines

Tags: cucumber, capybara

What is the difference when we write these two statements

Given

```
/^I see "(.*?)" field$/ do |text|
      page.has_content?(text)
```

and 
Given

```
/^I see "(.*?)" field$/ do |text|
      page.has_content?('text')
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the value that is passed to the `has_content?` method.

In the example:

```
Given /^I see "(.*?)" field$/ do |text|
  page.has_content?(text)
```

`text` is a variable that contains the string matched in the Cucumber step - ie the text between the quotations.

In the second example:

```
Given /^I see "(.*?)" field$/ do |text|
  page.has_content?('text')
```

`'text'` is a string with the value 'text'. It will always be that value.

Let us assume your feature has the step:

```
Given I see "my" field`
```

Then your first example `page.has_content?(text)` will check that the page has the text "my" on the page. In contrast, your second example `page.has_content?('text')` will always check that the page has the text "text" on the page. Basically your second example is hard-coding the `has_content?` method to always look for a specific text (rather than using the one specified in the Cucumber step).